# translateLoadingSuccess never gets called angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Im using angular-translate for translations and trying to avoid the FOUC.

```
angular.forEach(translations, function(translation){
  $translateProvider.translations(translation.locale, translation.translations);
});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(settings.defaultLocale);
```

and im trying to do this in one of my html

```
<h3 class="xxxx" translate translate-cloak>{{'ITEMS'}}</h3>
```

But i still see the FOUC behaviour. Any ideas or suggestions. When i debug the script I see the event $translateLoadingSuccess is never get called so all my elements are invisible even after page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid FOUC, What you are looking for is ng-cloak. You have to add it like this:

```
<body class="{{ bodyClass }}" ng-cloak>
```

and this will prevent unwanted flashing. [LINK TO ANGULAR DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Im already having ng-cloak but it doesnt work in cases where im rendering images from url ..when i land on the page.html. And thats when FOUC happens

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using ngBind. and then moved the translate login in a controller

```
$translate('KEY').then(function(newValue){
    $scope.KEY = newValue;
});
```

Also need to make sure yo use ngSanitize to setup in app.config